# the onCheckedChanged() method has no effect on the Swtich control

Tags: android

```
Switch viewSwitch = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cameraViewSwitch);
 viewSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mSettingsBarListener.onCameraViewSwitched(isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your actual question?  What are you trying to do?  Is the onCheckedChanged not being called?  Or is it being called but not doing what you want it to?

Comment: Add more details about your issue

Comment: I am trying to change the state of Switch so that I can show an popup but it is not going inside the onCheckedChanged() method

Comment: @PrashantKumar use isChecked for state of Switch

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
vkSwitch = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.vkSwitch);

vkSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                //do something
            }
            if (isChecked) {
               //do something
        }
    });

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/fbSwitch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textOff="OFF"
                    android:textOn="ON"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/customswitchselector"
                    android:track="@drawable/custom_track" />
```

Comment: @PrashantKumar show import "new OnCheckedChangeListener()"

Comment: @ PeDuCKA import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: <Switch
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textOn="on"
                    android:textOff="off"
                    android:id="@+id/newsletter_toggle" />

Comment: @PrashantKumar i don't know why standart swither not work for u, but support.SwitchCompat, work for me. I'm edit answer